# iOS didSelectRow not called on selection a row?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipickerview

I know its very basic question, but i'm facing a strange behaviour with `UIPickerView`.
Here is my scanario - I'm using `UIPickerView` in my app. my problem is that when i click on a row `didSelectRow` method is not called, however when i scroll rows of picker then its working. 
**more specific** assume that first row on picker is currently selected and if i click on 4th row then `didSelectRow` method not fired.
What am i missing?

UPDATE: if i comment this code from `viewDidLoad` method then all works fine-

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

and

```
-(void)dismissKeyboard {
    [numberTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [nameTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [cityTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [addressTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [zipTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIPickerView - 1st row selection does not call didSelectRow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788357/uipickerview-1st-row-selection-does-not-call-didselectrow)

Comment: @trojanfoe no its not duplicate of that question, i'm not interested on close picker view by tapping on selected row. Read my question again.

Comment: So if you leave the tap recognizer uncommented does the dismissKeyboard action fire when you touch a row in the Picker? Sounds like the tap recognizer is eating the touch events

Comment: @monkybonk05 yes if i leave the tap recognizer uncommented the dismissKeyboard action fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to use the tap gesture recognizer to dismiss the keyboard if they click anywhere in the view. The problem this is causing is now your UIPicker is not getting touch events passed to it. I have two ideas for possible solutions.

1) Inside the method:

> - (CGPoint)locationOfTouch:(NSUInteger)touchIndex inView:(UIView *)view

test the location and/or the view to determine if the picker was touched or not, and then forward the event.

2) Instead of adding the tap recognizer to the entire view, add an invisible subview to the likely tap area to close the keyboard that won't overlap the picker.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion by tomorrow.

Comment: Perfect i've a scroll view on my view so i added the tap recognizer to the scroll view and its working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding Gesture recognizer to other parts of self.view than the pickerview?

Comment: Gesture recognizer is added to my view(in viewDidLoad method) not on pickerView.

Comment: Yes, instead of adding gesture to entire view, you can add gesture recognizer only to view above pickerview.