# UIPickerView - 1st row selection does not call didSelectRow (in Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have a `UIPickerView` and when the user selects a row and press on a button called 'Start' the row selected will start a particular method.

To detect the selected row in the picker(and update the variable), I use the following code:

```
    var picked = 15

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        if row == 0 {
            picked = 1
       }
        else if row == 1 {
           picked = 2
       }
        else if row == 2 {
           picked = 3
       }
    }
```

This method is triggered whenever the user makes a CHANGE to the picker selection. But if the user does not select any value on the picker (bc the user want to select the 1st option which is already selected), this method is not called.

I know there is already a well answered question about this issue, but this for Objective C ([uipickerview-1st-row-selection-does-not-call-didselectrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788357/uipickerview-1st-row-selection-does-not-call-didselectrow?lq=1)). I want the answer for Swift, bc I have no OBjective C skills.

So my question: How can I let the 1st option of the picker, which is already selected, be detected as selected row by the user? (So this already-selected-row will update the variable)

I added to the code in `viewDidAppear`:

```
        picker1.selectRow(2, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
        // scrolls the specified row to center.
```

But this only SHOWS the specified row, but not RETURNS the specified row for the didSelectRow func. So this doesnt do it for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation says (at https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPickerViewDelegate/pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:) : "Called by the picker view when the user selects a row in a component.". Thus, you should rather query the state of the picker itself when it's getting dismissed via - (NSInteger)selectedRowInComponent:(NSInteger)component / func selectedRowInComponent(_ component: Int) -> Int .

Comment: I am not sure what u mean. But selectedRowInComponent is not what I need, that is for the component not for the row (I believe).

Comment: You just pass 0 for the component if you have 1 column in the picker view, and it will return you a 0-based index of the selected row.

Comment: tx for the effort, but this doesnt work for me. The already-selected-row in the picker (before the user selects a row) will not update the variable. So this is not 'registered'  by the didSelectRow func

Comment: picker1.selectRow(2, inComponent: 0, animated: true) will not cause the callback to work. If you decided to rely on this callback anyway, just call it yourself after you select the row.

Comment: yea indeed; picker1.selectRow(2, inComponent: 0, animated: true) does not cause it to work for me. I am not exactly sure what u mean by 'call it yourself after you select the row'. I will try tomorrow, when I am fresh again :). tx in advance

Comment: What I meant is that you should write something like that: picker1.delegate?.pickerView(picker1, didSelectRow: 2, inComponent: 0) right after you call picker1.selectRow(2, inComponent: 0, animated: true). One optional (but still important) note is that if you use the animated mode, you must take the duration of the animation into account (in order to keep the selected row property consistent with what you've got on GUI).

Comment: That worked! I had to unwrap, so the code used now: picker1.delegate?.pickerview!(picker1, didSelectRow: 2, inComponent: 0)

Comment: Thanks for your perseference! I am fairly new to swift, so that is why I did not really understand your previous answers and could not write the appropriate code.

Comment: I'm grateful for the upvote, but I'd like to be sure you managed to make it up and running. Have you solved the issue in the end?

Comment: Yes with your help I solved the issue and have managed to make it up and running, thanks alot!

Answer (score 4):

An easy user-friendly way to go around this problem is to have the row zero in each picker to be a user invitation rather than a value that is processed.  You can put something like 'Select' or '---' in the zero row.  This way the user will be forced to interact with the picker and will not rely on the default value that is passively sitting there. This is specially useful in multi-component pickers where the users may otherwise change some but not all of the components.