# How to pick the first option from Picker view?

Tags: swift

This question has already been answered here : [UIPickerView - 1st row selection does not call didSelectRow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788357/uipickerview-1st-row-selection-does-not-call-didselectrow/789633#789633) however, this is answered in objective C which I can not understand. He is also stating that the selected row is already "0", and mine has multiple choices.
It works when the user switched at least 1 time from the picker viewer. But I can not retrieve an answer when the user does not change anytime about the picker view. I am now using this:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    valueSelected = pickOption[row] as String
    print(valueSelected)
}
```

Than I use valueSelected as a reference, but this is not correct. What is the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make sure you have an outlet to the UIPickerView, you can get the currently selected option as follows:

```
let row = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
valueSelected = pickOption[row] as String
print(valueSelected)
```